# Pandas find, selecting and update two biggest values on each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, sorting

I have sorting/updating challenge. I would like to update two biggest values on each row into 'drop'. Each row can have different amount of Nan's. Values on each row can be in different ranges. There are no same values on any row. I have tried different kind of methods to achieve this but it seems it's harder than I thought! No for-loops please :)

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2, np.nan], 'col2': [2,3,3], 'col3': [3,6,5], 'col4': [4,9,10], 'col5': [5,1, np.nan], 'col6': [7,np.nan,2], 'col7': [np.nan, 5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Example:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 7 | Nan |
| 2 | 3 | 6 | 9 | 1 | Nan | 5 |
| Nan | 3 | 5 | 10 | Nan | 2 | 6 |

Should be converted as:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 'drop' | 'drop' | Nan |
| 2 | 3 | 'drop' | 'drop' | 1 | Nan | 5 |
| Nan | 3 | 5 | 'drop' | Nan | 2 | 'drop' |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.mask(df.eq(df.stack().sort_values(ascending=False).groupby(level=0).head(2).unstack()),'drop')
```

Here is another way.

```
df.mask(df.rank(axis=1,ascending=False).le(2),'drop')
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I just have to take my time and figure out what is going in there :)

Comment: Glad I could help. If this solved your question, please mark as completed so it does not stay open :)

Comment: The code brings the columns to the index using stack, and then sorts the values from largest to smallest. It then uses groupby to get the two largest (`head(2)`). `level=0` means the outermost level of the index. Then it brings it back to the format of the dataframe it started, but with only the columns if it contains one of the two biggest. Then it sees where the df's are equal and where its true, it replaces it with 'drop' using `mask()`.